# Not getting correct results from YouTube

Tags: python, html, urllib

I am working on a telegram bot with Python and I would love to add a feature where user says a song and bot get results from YouTube and sent audio file. I am doing this according to a documentation:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

param = "alone"
html = urlopen("https://www.yotube.com/results?search_query="+param)
print(html.read().decode())
```

This is the code and the result printed was

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en" data-adblockkey="MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDrp2lz7AOmADaN8tA50LsWcjLFyQFcb/P2Txc58oYOeILb3vBw7J6f4pamkAQVSQuqYsKx3YzdUHCvbVZvFUsCAwEAAQ==_sfXs9wqXsEHA+O7h90qdOyPox7d8zOuM0QltlSVHfKpLiRvwUH4ZRqU97Vkub3Ksm2+/4qe6/zRQKga85t1kFQ=="><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google.com" crossorigin></head><body><div id="target" style='opacity: 0'></div><script>window.park = "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";</script><script src="/js/parking.js?v=1622017026"></script></body></html>
```

The printed result was entirely different from documentation and not decoded perfectly for me to use its href and title and all other tags.

Comment: When I run your code I get an error. When I fix the typo (`yotube -> youtube`) I get a completely different result. Please post a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only Problem, but your URL is wrong, you wrote "yotube.com"

Comment: haha bro..later I noticed that..anyway thanks..xD